# Do I add modifiers to the Charisma check roll of 15 granted by the Glibness spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

While affected by the [*Glibness*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/glibness) spell, a creature can replace any Charisma check roll with a 15:

> Until the spell ends, when you make a Charisma check, you can replace the number you roll with a 15.

It's not clear to me from this wording whether the 15 replaces the roll before or after adding any modifiers. For example, if my modifier for a Charisma check is +5 and I choose to take the 15 from *Glibness*, is the resulting Charisma roll a 15 or a 20?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to the [SRD](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/systems-reference-document-srd) (p.77):

> To    make    an  ability check,  roll    a   d20 and add the relevant    ability modifier

*Glibness* can replace the Roll with a 15.

So, with a +5 CHA Bonus, instead of your Ability Check being 1d20 + 5, it can become 15 + 5, the d20 roll having been replaced by "15",  if you so choose.

If you have Proficiency in the Skill you are using (e.g. you are making a CHA (Deception) check, and you have Prof. in Deception), you may also add your Proficiency Bonus.

Comment: Jeremy Crawford also [agrees](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/869617852902285313) (unofficially).

Comment: Changing the emphasis from the word glibness to the word roll might help here, but +1 anyway.

Comment: There should be an honorable mention to the Bard's ability to add half their proficiency to any ability check.

Answer (score 13):

## "Roll" is not the same as "result"

The word "roll" literally refers to the roll of a die. Take, for example, the Great Weapon Fighting fighting style:

> #### Great Weapon Fighting
>
> When you roll a 1 or 2 on a damage die for an attack you make with a melee weapon that you are wielding with two hands, you can reroll the die and must use the new roll, even if the new roll is a 1 or a 2. The weapon must have the two-handed or versatile property for you to gain this benefit.

The "roll" refers to the actual number shown on the die.

The "result" is a different matter. It is the total value after applying all modifiers. Take, for example, the indomitable might class feature of the barbarian:

> #### Indomitable Might
>
> Beginning at 18th level, if your total for a Strength check is less
> than your Strength score, you can use that score in place of the
> total.

For *glibness*, you can adjust the d20 roll you make to be 15 regardless of what you actually rolled.